# Can't destroy a session with this script?

Tags: php, session

I am unable to unset this session in this script resulting in an error. I know it's the session because when I restart my browser it works again.

Script:

```
if (isset($_POST['file_upload_submit']) && isset($name) && $delete_after == '1 Day') {
    if (!empty($name)) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['file_id'] = uniqid('');
        $location_1_day = 'uploads/1/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '/' . $name;
        $refresh_1_day = 'uploads/1/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '.php';
        mkdir('uploads/1/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '/');
        mkdir('uploads/1/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '/' . $_SESSION['file_id']);
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $location_1_day)) {       
                $handle_1_day = fopen('uploads/1/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '/' . $_SESSION['file_id'] . '.php', 'w');
                fwrite($handle_1_day, '<?PHP require(\'../../../template_1.php\'); ?>');
                session_destroy();
                header('Location: '.$refresh_1_day.''); 
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads//template_1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTING_SERVER\KronoFiles\uploads\index.php on line 110`

AND

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpEF6B.tmp' to 'uploads//template_1.php' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTING_SERVER\KronoFiles\uploads\index.php on line 110`

Comment: sessions don't work anymore when you restart the browser...

Comment: Exactly, I can't unset this session after the script runs though. I am trying to unset it with `session_destroy` but it is not working.

Comment: try with `unset($_SESSION['session_name']);`

Comment: What's the error...................?

Comment: Is the file moved successfully and are you redirected to the created `.php` file?

Comment: The first time I upload it is successful, but the second time it cannot define a new session therefor the session did not unset.

Comment: Just tried `unset()` and it gives me this `Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads//template_1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTING_SERVER\KronoFiles\uploads\index.php on line 110` AND `Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpEF6B.tmp' to 'uploads//template_1.php' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTING_SERVER\KronoFiles\uploads\index.php on line 110`

Comment: @user3399072 the error is important, because when you have a problem you debug it. If there's an error, that will give you a starting point to look at. Since you haven't provided enough relevant information here this question will probably get voted to be closed until you do. There could be a million things you are potentially outputting before this code which would cause `session_start()` to fail, which in turn would mean `session_destroy()` won't work. Don't be so naive, this is a forum of professionals and if you want help do as we say.

Comment: I just posted the error that it gives me

Comment: @user3399072 well there you go. Since your `session_destroy()` call relies on the upload being **successful**, that's why it isn't being destroyed. Fix your file uploading (your target URL is wrong)

Comment: The upload is successful, the only time it isn't is after a session has been set...